# Small issue with latex!

Tags: notation

I'm a high school student doing a research on LaTeX. I'm learning in the process of doing so, however, I can't find anywhere how to express the following:

[image]

Comment: you should rather ask this on [meta](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Or on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: "Software that mathematicians use" is part of the scope of this group.

Comment: What part of the desired formula is giving you trouble?  Or in other words, what is your best approximation to what you want?

Comment: @MatthewDaly Questions about software used by mathematicians are, in principle, on topic here.  However, when there is a dedicated SE site for a particular package, it is better to ask there.  Thus, for example, this question would be a better fit for [tex.se], and questions about Mathematica are probably better asked at [mathematica.se].

Comment: In this particular case, I think that pointing the asker towards [tex.se] has additional benefits, as the context provided in the question indicates that the asker may have many additional questions in the future, and knowing of the existence of the TeX SE site may provide additional benefits down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\nabla f=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1^{n-1} \\
        x_2^{n-1} \\
        \vdots \\
        x_n^{n-1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Here is the syntax used:

```
$$
\nabla f=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1^{n-1} \\
        x_2^{n-1} \\
        \vdots \\
        x_n^{n-1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
```

Comment: hint: if you "try" to edit this answer, you'll see the code Lulu made to generate it.

Comment: Or left click on the code and choose show math as Tex commands